# Can I use a shallow box to install a 240v outlet?

Tags: wiring

I need to move a 240v receptacle behind existing drywall that is affixed to the block wall on furring strips.

Can I use a shallow plastic box to install the receptacle?

Comment: Fill limits depend on the number of wires. Is this a 240V **only** receptacle or is a 240V/120V receptacle (like for a typical dryer or oven)? What size (Amps) circuit breaker? What size (AWG) are the existing wires?

Comment: Where in the world is this? Rules vary.

Answer (score 2):

[Assuming USA/Canada location/rules] So long as your box fill is met, yes.

However, there are multiple reasons to not prefer a plastic box, at least one of which relates to box fill - internal clamps count against box fill, while external clamps as more typically used with steel boxes do not count against box fill.

Another is that if this is a large 240VAC outlet as for a range or dryer, the forces involved in plugging and unplugging those are significant, and your plastic box may break, where a steel one would not.

Box fill is: your plastic box should be marked with a number of cubic inches (usually just XY C.I. where X and Y are numbers) - steel boxes have standard volumes which can be looked up in a table. Each wire that terminates in the box adds to the wire count. The receptacle adds 2 to the wire count. Internal clamps add 1 to the wire count. The size (gauge) of each wire corresponds to a number of cubic inches required for each wire "count" of that size - 2.0 for 14 gauge, 2.25 for 12 gauge, 2.5 for 10 gauge, 3.0 for 8 gauge and 5.0 for 6 gauge. The box needs to be at least as large as all those added up (larger is fine) - if you are "depth-limited" you may require a box that is higher and wider than you anticipate, depending on how many and what size wires you are using (i.e. 6 gauge wires for a 50A range receptacle need a lot of room.)

*Unlikely to come into play unless your receptacle is "in-line" with another - up to 4 grounding wires are counted as 1 of the largest size grounding wire. After that they are (as of 2020 code) counted as 1/4 (so one counts as 1, 3 count as 1, but 5 count as 1.25)*

Comment: Also, steel boxes are *inherently* low-profile: stock sizes are 4x4x1.5" (only 1.5" deep) or the deeps are 2-1/8" deep. That's tiny compared to plastic boxes which are the depth of a 2x4.  Also the steel box will do a much, much better job of catching arc faults, and will be easier to fit up too - the ground wire goes to the steel box so  you only need to wrestle 3 wires to the recep (which gets its ground via steel-steel contact).